# Are Windows 8 language packs translated completely?

Tags: windows-8, language

Are Windows 8 language packs translated completely? Meaning when I install Windows 8 in english and install a german language pack (or any language pack), that when switch to german **everything** will be shown in german.

In Windows 7 Ultimate when I installed a language pack, I still had a "main language" and some of the texts weren't translated so I end up with a mix of two different languages, which I'm trying to avoid now.

Comment: It depends on the language. The important languages like German are fully translated.